# Css circle border-radius pixelated after render

Tags: css, border

[image]

```
`width: 35px;
height: 35px;
background: #000000;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;`
```

It's showing pixelated.

Comment: Try radius as 100% instead of 100px

Comment: @ShalineeSIngh I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code you are working with?

Comment: width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .2s;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 3px;

Here is the css code

Comment: please add the html code also.

Comment: @ShalineeSIngh <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="top-icon-fb" title="Like us on Facebook">
         <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/facebook.png">
        </a>